# Where are files uploaded by Valums?! (i have to store them in mysql database with PHP)

Tags: php

when i upload several files using [Valmus Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload), how can i "work with them", ie. store in mysql database, crop or resize, etc...

but, where are those files, and how can i access them?

tnx in adv!!!

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` will show you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, all i had to do is to set that action file is php.php, from server directory
;-)

tnx to all!

Answer (score 2):

PHP puts a list of uploaded files in the $_FILES global variable (see doc here : http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php ).

You can iterate over uploaded files like this:

```
foreach($_FILES as $file) {
    // $file['tmp_name'] is where the file resides on the disk
    // use move_uploaded_file() to move it elsewhere
    // $file['name'] is the name of the file on the sender's computer
}
```

Comment: understand that, but what's their (form) name?

Comment: tnx, but if i put your code in file do-nothing.php (just to mention that i changed action file from do-nothing.htm to do-nothing.php and proper code in demo.html), i get Failed as a result of file upload... what did i missed?

Answer (score 0):

action: `../server/php.php` ,

files will be in `server/uploads` when using the demo, make sure you `CHMOD 777` this directory